# Inherting and Customizing WPF controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

We are developing a piece of software that is intended to work both as a stand alone as well as a plugin to different CAD programs. Note that this is meant to be discrete versions of the software. Not one monolith version that functions as a plugin as well as a stand alone version. For this we are developing an interface using WPF. Depending on the context (i.e. whether it is the stand alone version or hooked up to a CAD program) I want to be able to change the look and most importantly the behaviour of the interface. I would rather not have to rewrite the entire interface.

I will give a brief overview of my failed idea as I hope it will provide some additional context to what I want to achieve. My initial idea was to create project that defines a default interface by creating the necessary controls and assembling them to an interface in a page or a window. If I then want to customize the interface for use with a specific CAD program I inherit from the controls and pages and override the parts I want to customize for a given context. However I found that inherit from WPF controls is not straight forward.

A quick mock up of the setup I tried is outlined [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4ijR.jpg).

The default view contains a basic interface called DefaultUI collected in a page. Currently it only contains a custom canvas(called DefaultCanvas) type wrapped in a scrollviewer. The XAML code for the DefaultUI is.

```
<Page x:Class="DefaultView.DefaultUI"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DefaultView"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    Title="DefaultUI">

    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <local:DefaultCanvas x:Name="mCanvas" 
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent"
                         AllowDrop="True" IsHitTestVisible="True">
            </local:DefaultCanvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

What I tried in the CADView and StandAlone project is to create derived classes like CADViewCanvas and CADViewUI from DefaultCanvas and DefaultUI and be able to customize the behaviour of these. Actually I mostly want to customize the behaviour of the canvas, but the CADViewUI needs to use the derived class rather than the DefaultCanvas. The reason I also want to derive from the DefaultUI is that it might contain several controls and I only want to customize the one. It was about here that I realized that I might have the wrong idea as the I assume that mCanvas would be initialized to an instance of DefaultCanvas when CADViewUI calls it's base constructor.

The additional functionality needed in CADViewCanvas is the logic connects to theCAD software in question. In CADView a set of wrappers is included. each wrapper connects a object from our model to an object in the CAD software. The CADViewCanvas should thus work with this wrapper, instead of directly on the model object. The same action is taken for the model object, but extra logic is needed to keep the CAD object up to date as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance of controls that contain child controls can be very hard when you want to adjust the child control in the derived classes.

I would advice to only have controls in the base class that you can customize through styles. Applying a different style to a child control in a derived class is 'easy' and clean: just define a new style (that can be based on the default style)

When you need different behavior of controls you will need to provide that behavior in some way:

1. Put all possible behaviors in the base class and add properties to turn them on and off so these can be set in the style. This requires you to know upfront what will be needed and will create bloated controls. I recommend against this.
2. Or implement different controls. This means that you cannot add these to the base control and you will have to add them to the derived controls. Much cleaner in my opinion.

In short: Functionality that is not the same for all derived classes does not belong in a base class so do not put it there. If it is simple, visual things like layout/colors/visibility a style might be a proper solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The functionality i want to implement in the DefaultCanvas is the actions needed to be taken in my own model. This is the same for all projects. However, when hooking up with a CAD program some extra needs to be done. Mostly making coresponding changes in the CAD software.

As I understand your comment i would be able to do this with controls like the DefaultCanvas, But controls containing other controls would have to reimplemented with every end project. I.e. in this case for both CADView and stand alone, although they are the same apart for the canvas used.

Comment: That "extra" bit, is it visually or pure logic? If logic it belongs in the model and not in the controls

Comment: The extra bit is ensuring that the CAD software's representation is consistent with our model. It can't be incorperated directly into our model as it needs to be able run indepently of the CAD software. This is done through a separate project of  connects the model and the view. This connection is only needed when the model is connected to a CAD program. Thus it is not included directly in the model. The extra bit needed is the managing of this connection.

Comment: @Taus - What you are describing does not belong in a control. It belongs in a data/model layer.So perhaps the layering you currently have is wrong and you need another data/model layer between the base view and the model that is only active when running in the CAD program.

Comment: I'll just elaborate a bit on our design, as it seems necessary. We are not using a standard MVVM pattern. There are several projects that is not included in the mock up i showed as i did not deem them necessary to include. However it seems one of them might be relevant. We have a library that defines all the visuals and only the visuals. The model does not know anything about this library and it does not know anything about the model. The DefaultView and CADView use this library to create the visuals. Thus, these  actually act perform both the job of the view and the viewmodel. Continued

Comment: Thus the names might be a bit badly chose. In DefaultView it needs to be communicated back to a model object when something changes and vice versa. Inside CADView is a set of wrappers that connects a CAD object with a corresponding Model object. When something changes it needs to be communicated back to the model as well as the CAD object. 

All of this works already and i can create an inteface that does what i want. However i would have to reimplement the "assembly" of the interface if i want to support other CAD software. I.e. combining the canvas and other controls into the final interface

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you could use some form of dependency injection so the application can decide at runtime what implementations to load. (This comment section is getting too much out of hand; please add relevant information to the question or delete the question. Currently it is hardly useful for anyone else but you)

Comment: The intention is not to make a single version that can act as both a plugin and stand alone, but rather to create discrete versions with a specific purpose. Thus it should be decided at compile time. I've edited the question to reflect this as well as the other things mentioned here in the comments. I realize that this might not be super usefull for other people though as it seems somewhat specific to my case. Is there somewhere better to go with something like this?

Comment: On Stackoverflow a question such as: "how do I switch between implementations at compile time?" Would be fine. For design questions, best practices and opinions ProgrammersStackExchange might be a better place.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Whiteboard and design questions are welcome on Programmers.SE. Anything opinion-based is off-topic there, same as on Stack Overflow. Please read: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/22815)**.

Comment: Thanks @Snowman I still have trouble figuring out what is and isn't on topic on Programmers.SE

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Every Stack Exchange site has [What topics can I ask about here?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Anyway. Thanks for you help. It got me a bit further. When i get a more clear idea of what i need i might reframe the question in a more general way that is not so reliant on our needs for this specific project.